# Flutter: Number picker Horizontal Scroll and selected item always in middle

Tags: flutter, numberpicker

I am working on the number picker with horizontal scroll and the view looks like in the below image.

[image]

I have tried to customize [this](https://github.com/andrezanna/NumberPicker) library as per my requirement. But after customize, it looks like this

[image]

There is [listwheelscrollview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html) for the vertical scroll and for horizontal its added for the new feature https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25074

Any alternative solution for now to make the same view?

Comment: hi, @Sunny! I have the same problem, do you have any solution? I need the same number picker as you wanted. Selected biggest one, and the other going smaller and smaller. I would be happy if you can help me with that.

Comment: @NurbekBatyrzhanuulu No, I did not find any solution for this.